# Creating Google Location URL by using latitude & longitude information

Tags: android, location, linkify

[image][image]

I have a code where I'm retrieving latitude and longitude information. I'm interested to show that information on map. I would like to create a link for Google map with retrieved "longitude" and "latitude" information. I am using [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) for this as follows:

**** Java Code**:

```
 String text = "maps.google.com/?q=latitude,longitude";
 TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
 label.setText(text);
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("maps.google.com");
 Linkify.addLinks(label, pattern, "http://");
```

But this code is not working. Can someone help me with code?
I am getting something like following. My longitude and latitude are not getting linked with rest of the url.

Comment: try my code might it help you to make the link and set the on click listener on textview.

Answer (score 2):

you may use below code for displaying map

```
    String url = "geo:" +  sLatitude + "," + sLongitude +"?z=22&q="+sLatitude + "," + sLongitude;
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
```

above code shows map using google map application installed in your phone, it also mark the location with zoom level of 22. **No google map api key** required

Hope this will help...

Comment: i dont wanna display map itself with intent .I want the hyperlink comes over the textview from there if i click then the google map gets opened with latitude longitude information in my code.and after that this link send as SMS to other ....

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the [`android:autoLink`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aautoLink) attribute of the `TextView` to convert the string into links. It controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links.

For example, you may add it in your layout (`.xml`) file.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/google_map_url"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

It will automatically convert the text into links for you. Hope it helps you :)